# Having issues saving the dynamic state of a checkbox (Javascript, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to make a form where it allows you to proceed to another webpage if a checkbox has been checked, and prompts you with an alert otherwise.

My issue is that the checkbox won't save the state dynamically. As a result, I have to refresh the page everytime I check the checkbox in order to proceed to the next webpage. Is there something I need to add to my code? I've attached the javascript function, the PHP page that changes the state in the SQL, as well as the line where I call the function itself.

Javascript function:

```
        //This function handles the clicking of checkboxes in the list
        //It sends an ajax POST message to a separate php file that handles the database updating
        function checkboxClicked(checkboxType, ticketNumber){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'updateCheckbox.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {checkboxType: checkboxType, ticketNumber: ticketNumber},

                success: function(result, status){
                    if (status != "success"){
                        console.log("Status: " + status + ", Result: " + result);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

PHP file (updatecheckbox.php)

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
$strCnn = "Provider=sqloledb; Data Source=booty;Initial Catalog=booty;Trusted_Connection=Yes";

$conn->open($strCnn);

$strSQL  = "UPDATE tblScantronTickets SET ".$_POST['checkboxType']."=";
$strSQL .= "(SELECT ~".$_POST['checkboxType']." FROM tblScantronTickets WHERE TicketNumber=".$_POST['ticketNumber'].")";
$strSQL .= " WHERE TicketNumber=".$_POST['ticketNumber'];

try {
    $conn->Execute($strSQL);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode($e);
}

echo json_encode("SUCCESS!");

?>
```

PHP line where I call the function:

```
$strHTML .= "<td align='center'> <input type='checkbox' ".$received." class='receivedCheckbox' onchange='checkboxClicked(\"Received\", ".$ticketNumber.")'/> </td>\n";
```

Comment: this script won't locate to another url.. i can't understand your question. If you need to submit the form after the checkbox is checked you have to had a "form.submit" after the ajax success.. or you need to redirect to another page after saving the checkbox state?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. If the check box is inside a form, it will submit with the correct state regardless of whether you updated the database or not. Could you please clarify what you wish to do?

Comment: I just showed a portion of my code. What I want to do is if the checkbox is checked, allow to proceed to next page. Otherwise, don't proceed. As of now, I have to refresh the page everytime I change the checkbox state. For example, if the checkbox is unchecked, I have to check it and refresh the page before I can proceed. I want it so I don't have to refresh, just click the checkbox and go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is to get the state of a checkbox before proceed to the next page, you can use jQuery.

```
$('#checkbox').is(':checked');
```

This will return true if it is checked and false if it is not